# JavaScript Fetch() Not Differentiating Between The Update And Delete Functionality Of A Form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, fetch-api

I have a form that is currently processed on the server with PHP/MySQL that uses the JavaScript fetch() API in the frontend so that when details are submitted to the database the page doesn't reload on form submission.

The form(s) themselves are within a loop that outputs multiple instances of the form onto the page.

For the JavaScript to work it relies on the following PHP (I will show more detailed code at the end of the question)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // PHP to process form details
}
```

The javascript is:

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

forms.forEach(item => {
    
    item.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    
        evt.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(this);

        fetch("upload-details.php", {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }).then(function(response){
            return response.text();
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.error(error);
        })

        // remove item after form details submitted
        item.remove();

    })

})
```

I now wish to add a delete button that also works with the JS fetch API. The problem I have is, I can't get the JS Fetch to differentiate between when the form details are updated and when the record should be deleted?

I've tried changing this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // PHP to process form details (both update and delete)
}
```

To this (to no avail):

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    // PHP to process form details
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    // PHP to process form details
}
```

When I turn off the JS fetch() API code, the code below behaves exactly as expected from the PHP / MySQL point of view (i.e. it updates and deletes the records accordingly).

MORE DETAILED CODE:

```
<?php
isset($_REQUEST['username']) ? $username = $_REQUEST['username'] : header("Location: login.php");

// the following variable is already fetched with PHP from the database
// it is added as a value to a hidden input element in the HTML form shown below
$db_image_id = htmlspecialchars($row['image_id']);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
    $image_title = $_POST['image-title'];
    $image_tags = $_POST['image-tags'];
    $image_id = $_POST['image-id']; // value attribute from hidden form element

    if(empty(trim($image_title))){
        $error[] = "Image Title cannot be blank";
    }

    if (!isset($error)) {

        try {

            $sql = "UPDATE imageposts SET
            image_title = :image_title,
            image_tags = :image_tags

            WHERE image_id = :image_id";
                
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    
            $stmt->execute([
                ':image_title' => $image_title,
                ':image_tags' => $image_tags,
                ':image_id' => $image_id
            ]);
                    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    } else {
        // give values an empty string to avoid an error being thrown before form submission if empty
        $image_title = $image_tags = "";
    }

}

//---- DELETE DETAILS
if(isset($_POST['upload-details-delete'])) {

    $image_id = $_POST['image-id']; // 'value' attribute from hidden form element

    try {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `lj_imageposts` WHERE image_id = :id";
            
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([
            ':id' => $image_id
        ]);
                
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}

// data is fetched with PHP to add to the form 
//(I haven't included this code because there is a lot of values outputted onto the form, and when the JavaScript fetch() is turned off it all works OK)
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

?>

<!-- form that holds the update and delete elements -->
<div class="upload-details-component">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button name="delete">Delete</button>
        <div class="upload-details-image-wrapper">
            <!-- ** image is outputted here from database ** -->
        </div>
        <div class="edit-zone">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>Image Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="image-title" placeholder="Image Title" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>Image Tags</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="image-tags"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="COMPLETE UPLOAD">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="image-id" value="<?php echo $db_image_id?>">
    </form>    
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well what does the client-side "delete" code look like? You didn't post that.

Comment: hi@Pointy - because it's in the same form as the "update" functionality it doesn't have any separate client side code? Is that where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your code explicitly sets the HTTP method to "POST".

Comment: @Pointy - that's because I'm posting the data? If that is incorrect what would I do instead? Do you know how to solve the issue? I'm new to all this. Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit buttons added to POST data only when user clicked it. Since you are collecting form data in javascript, no buttons are clicked, hens they are not included.

What you'll need to do is find out which submit button was clicked and manually add either a hidden input field with such information before you collect form data, or inject into formdata itself:

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

forms.forEach(item => {

  item.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.set(evt.submitter.name, evt.submitter.value);

    console.log([...formData].join("|"));

  })

})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="test" value="blah">
  <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="hidblah">
  <button type="submit" name="update" value="upd">update</button>
  <button type="submit" name="delete" value="del">delete</button>
</form>
```

Since not all browsers yet support [`event.submitter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) you'll need track which button was clicked via onclick event:

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

forms.forEach(item => {

  item.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"], button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", e => item._button = button); //store this button in the form element
  })

  item.addEventListener("submit", function(evt, btn) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);
    if (this._button) //submitted by a button?
    {
      formData.set(this._button.name, this._button.value);
      delete this._button; //this only needed if form can be submitted without submit button (aka submitted by javascript)
    }

    console.log([...formData].join("|"));
  });
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="test" value="blah">
  <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="hidblah">
  <button type="submit" name="update" value="upd">update</button>
  <button type="submit" name="delete" value="del">delete</button>
  <button name="submit" value="sub">submit</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input name="test2" value="blah2">
  <input type="hidden" name="hid2" value="hidblah2">
  <button type="submit" name="update2" value="upd2">update2</button>
  <button type="submit" name="delete2" value="del2">delete2</button>
  <button name="submit2" value="sub2">submit2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't use this answer because `.submitter` isn't available on iOS Safari.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain the `item._button = button` part. I don't understand what is going on there (I've never seen a dot and underscore together in javascript before)? Or indeed something assigned like that.

Comment: Variable/property name started with underscore is just formality, it's a common practice use it as an indicator for "private use only" (not really though, it's not enforced by javascript). So `item` is an object of `<form>` html element, I'm using it to store the clicked button element, this way no other variables have to be declared. This is just another way share data between different scopes if needed as well.

Comment: thanks @vanowm. Today there was a 'drive-by' on the question, not just the answer. Annoying and pathetic.